# Erro ao acessar classe dao por uma classe teste

Tags: java, testes, junit, testes-de-unidade

Estou com o seguinte erro, ao acessar uma classe dao de uma classe de teste:

java.lang.NullPointerException

Esse é o método do controller:

```
@Post("/consultar_lancamento/{codLancamento}")
public int consultarLancamento(int codLancamento) {
    try {
        Lancamento lancamento = lancamentoDao.carregaPorId(codLancamento);
        result.use(json()).withoutRoot().from(lancamento).serialize();
        contaLinhasDoLancamento(lancamento);  
    } catch (Exception err) {
        Lancamento lancamento = new Lancamento();          
        lancamento.setDescricaoLancamento(null);
        result.use(json()).withoutRoot().from(lancamento).serialize();
        return 0;
    }  
    return codLancamento;
}
```

Esse é o método da classe de teste:

```
@Test
public void testConsultarLancamento() {
    EditarLancamentoController instanciaEditarLancamentoController = new EditarLancamentoController();
    int resultadoDaConsultaUm = instanciaEditarLancamentoController.consultarLancamento(4);      
    int resultadoDaConsultaNulo = instanciaEditarLancamentoController.consultarLancamento(0);      
    assertEquals(4, resultadoDaConsultaUm);
    assertEquals(0, resultadoDaConsultaNulo);
}
```

Observação: Estou usando Injeção de dependências.
O erro ocorre no momento de acessar o método DAO, verifiquei o projeto para ver se era a injeção, e não encontrei problemas de configuração.

Descrição do erro:

```
Testsuite: br.com.uprise.controller.EditarLancamentoControllerTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1,125 sec

Testcase: testConsultarLancamento(br.com.uprise.controller.EditarLancamentoControllerTest): Caused an ERROR
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.uprise.controller.EditarLancamentoController.consultarLancamento(EditarLancamentoController.java:106)
    at br.com.uprise.controller.EditarLancamentoControllerTest.testConsultarLancamento(EditarLancamentoControllerTest.java:52)


Test br.com.uprise.controller.EditarLancamentoControllerTest FAILED
```

Comment: Adiciona a pilha de erro completa.

Comment: @diegofm, adicionei a descrição

Comment: Onde você utiliza codLancamentoRecebido dentro de consultarLancamento não deveria ser codLancamento? Acho que o problema é esse...

Comment: Corrigir variável, porém nada mudou.

Comment: Você está usando spring para a injeção de dependências? Utiliza JPA nos seus daos? Se usa jpa, a conexão no banco de dados está no container ou no persistence.xml?

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra estou utilizando o pico container e uso JPA nos daos. minha conexao esta no persistence

Comment: Por acaso é a variável `lancamentoDao` que está nula? Você inicializou esta variável antes de chamar o método `consultarLancamento` pelo teste?

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre pois sua variável lancamentoDao está nula.

O seu motor de injeção dependência (pelo que entendi é o pico) não está sendo executado no teste, por isso ele não injeta as dependências do seu controller nele.

Para uma solução mais simples, você pode criar um construtor que receba a dependência do controller, e no seu teste utilizar um Mock para simular o que sua dependência deveria fazer

Recomendo utilizar o framework [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) para facilitar nos mocks.

Seu controller:

```
public class EditarLancamentoController(LancamentoDao lancamentoDao) {
    this.lancamentoDao = lancamentoDao;
}
```

No seu test:

```
@Test
public void testConsultarLancamento() {
    LancamentoDao lancamentoDao = Mockito.mock(LancamentoDao.class);
    EditarLancamentoController instanciaEditarLancamentoController = new EditarLancamentoController(lancamentoDao);
    int resultadoDaConsultaUm = instanciaEditarLancamentoController.consultarLancamento(4);      
    int resultadoDaConsultaNulo = instanciaEditarLancamentoController.consultarLancamento(0);      
    assertEquals(4, resultadoDaConsultaUm);
    assertEquals(0, resultadoDaConsultaNulo);
}
```